# How to display the ToString of an object which is in a ListBox?

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I have a class which holds the string I want to display and an id for that item.

```
ref class ListBoxItem {
private:
   int id;
   String ^ name;

public:
   ListBoxItem(int id, const char * name) { this->id = id; this->name = gcnew System::String(name); }
   virtual String ^ ToString() new { return name; }
};
```

And I add each item to the ListBox like this:

```
for(list<string>::iterator i = listItems.begin(); i != listItems.end(); i++)
   listBoxItems->Items->Add(gcnew ListBoxItem(2, (*i).c_str()));
```

This will produce a `ListBox` with the correct number of items, but all the items are called "ListBoxItem".

Instead, I want the `ListBox` to display the string which is produced when the `ToString` method is invoked on `ListBoxItem`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say whether you were using WinForms or WPF, but I believe this answer is valid for either.

(Note: There is a class named [ListBoxItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem.aspx) in the framework. You might want to pick a different class name.)

I believe the issue is here:

```
virtual String ^ ToString() new { return name; }
                            ^^^
```

This means you're creating a brand new ToString method, which doesn't have anything to do with the Object.ToString method. When the ListBox calls ToString, it doesn't have your class definition, so it just calls Object.ToString(), which you haven't changed.

Switch it to this, and you should be good:

```
virtual String ^ ToString() override { return name; }
                            ^^^^^^^^
```